# RedmineでREST API経由でのチケット登録ができない

Tags: redmine

RedmineでREST API経由でチケットを登録しようとするのですが、エラー422で登録ができません。
xml形式でPOSTしているのですが、Bodyを見ても不備があるようには見えません。
何か設定などが足らないのでしょうか？

Rubyのソースコードでエラーが出ましたが、Firefoxのアドオン(RESTClient)を使ってもエラーが出ます。

URL
[http://IPアドレス/issues.xml?key=キー値](http://IP%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9/issues.xml?key=%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E5%80%A4)
※ブラウザからはhttp://IPアドレス/issues.xmlでアクセスできることを確認済み

Body
画像の通りです↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラー内容(Body部)
画像の通りです↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 文字コードは指定してますか？

Comment: 試しに題名や説明の内容全て英数字で送ってみてはどうでしょう

Answer (score 3):

Redmine 公式のAPI仕様によると,
status というフィールドはなく、status_id です。
確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues#Creating-an-issue

Answer (score 0):

私も同じ症状でしたが、HTTPヘッダを"Content-Type:application/xml"へ
修正したら、正常終了しました。（コピー元の"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"のまま使っていたのが原因のようです)
エラー422が出る場合はXMLとして認識に失敗している可能性が高いと思います。
情報共有のために記述しました。